# Android app read extended advertising from Nordic nrf52840 nrf connect v2.0.0 periodic_adv

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I can find my device but I want to read the extended advertising data which my nrf52840 is advertising I try to print out the ScanResult but it only print out my device name, then I tried to print out the ManufacturerSpecificData it return my {}. My phone is Sony Xperia 1 with bluetooth 5.0 android version 10

```
package com.example.tryble_scanner;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;
private boolean mScanning = false;
private Handler mHandler = null;

private ScanCallback mLeScanCallBack1 = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
                //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                String data=ConverttoString(result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData());
                BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();
                byte[] scanRecord =result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
                String s=new String(scanRecord,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Log.d("BLE", btdevice.getAddress());
                Log.d("BLE",s);

            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.d("BLE", "error");
            }
};

private  ScanCallback mLeScanCallBack2=new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.d("BLE","scan stop");
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.d("BLE","stop scan failed");
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void stop_scan(View view) {
    Log.d("Ble","scan stop pressed");
//        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(mLeScanCallBack2);
}

public void onBtnScan(View view) {
    Log.i("Btn","get click");
    checkBTPermission();
    String[] names=new String[]{"Auden test"};
    List<ScanFilter> filters=null;
    if(names != null){
        filters=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name:names){
            ScanFilter filter=new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build();
            filters.add(filter);
        }
    }
    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            //.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            //.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            //.setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
            //.setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
            //.setReportDelay(0L)
              .setLegacy(false)
              .build();
    if(mBluetoothLeScanner==null){
        Log.i("BLE","could not get scanner");
    }else{
        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters,scanSettings,mLeScanCallBack1);  //filters,scanSettings,mLeScanCallback
    }
}

private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d("BLE","checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
public static String ConverttoString (SparseArray<byte[]> array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return "null";
    }
    if (array.size() == 0) {
        return "{}";
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append('{');
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        buffer.append(array.keyAt(i)).append("=").append(Arrays.toString(array.valueAt(i)));
    }
    buffer.append('}');
    Log.d("convert",buffer.toString());
    return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

nrf52840

```
 /*
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Nordic Semiconductor ASA
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>

static uint8_t mfg_data[] = { 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10};

static const struct bt_data ad[] = {
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA, mfg_data, 40),
};

void main(void)
{
struct bt_le_ext_adv *adv;
int err;

printk("Starting Periodic Advertising Demo\n");

/* Initialize the Bluetooth Subsystem */
err = bt_enable(NULL);
if (err) {
    printk("Bluetooth init failed (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Create a non-connectable non-scannable advertising set */
err = bt_le_ext_adv_create(BT_LE_EXT_ADV_NCONN_NAME, NULL, &adv); //  BT_LE_EXT_ADV_NCONN_NAME  BT_LE_EXT_ADV_SCAN_NAME
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to create advertising set (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Set periodic advertising parameters */
err = bt_le_per_adv_set_param(adv, BT_LE_PER_ADV_DEFAULT);
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to set periodic advertising parameters"
           " (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Enable Periodic Advertising */
err = bt_le_per_adv_start(adv);
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to enable periodic advertising (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

while (true) {
    printk("Start Extended Advertising...");
    err = bt_le_ext_adv_start(adv, BT_LE_EXT_ADV_START_DEFAULT);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to start extended advertising "
               "(err %d)\n", err);
        return;
    }
    printk("done.\n");

    err=bt_le_per_adv_set_data(adv,ad,ARRAY_SIZE(ad));
    if(err){
        printk("Failed (err %d)\n",err);
        return;
    }


    k_sleep(K_SECONDS(3000));

    printk("Stop Extended Advertising...");
    err = bt_le_ext_adv_stop(adv);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to stop extended advertising "
               "(err %d)\n", err);
        return;
    }
    printk("done.\n");

    k_sleep(K_SECONDS(1));
}
}
```

[image: print getManufacturerSpecificData]

[image: print ScanRecord]
[image: device information]

Comment: please show us the [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=de&gl=US) [Device Information](https://www.xda-developers.com/check-bluetooth-5-all-features-supported/)

Comment: I can see that you edited your post, but I can't see anything like [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/files/2019/03/Screenshot_20190325-233228_nRF-Connect-1-498x1024.jpg)

Comment: @Risto I know that you post a link on my previous post I click on Bluetooth product test then I have no clue what should I do next

Comment: please install nRF Connect app on your Xperia mobile and show us the *Device Information* screen

Comment: You should check if you can see the extended advertising with the nRF Connect app. However, in my limited experience with *Zephyr* I can see that you define a bigger BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA chunk, but according to your source code it is never used

Comment: @Risto I think my device did use the mfg_data cause I have another nordic device which is receiving the data and it can read what's inside mfg_data

Comment: @Risto Sorry bro I found out that I forget to call bt_le_per_set_data() function to add the mfg_data[] in to advertising my bad I should have check my code first, I have add the function in to my code, but my app still can't get the extended advertising, is there something I did wrong?