# Make Android app get bluetooth manufacturer data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on an Android app android 10 and nordic nrf52840 which is advertising at channel 37,38,39 I want to get the manufacturer data from my nordic bluetooth device. Like the picture shown below. Now I can scan and find my device, but I don't know how to get manufacturer data.

```
package com.example.test373839;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.BatchingListUpdateCallback;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter=null;
private BluetoothManager mbluetoothManager=null;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

}

public void StartScan(View view) {
    Log.d("Button","click");
    checkBTPermission();
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    IntentFilter dicoveryDeviceIntent=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver,dicoveryDeviceIntent);
}
private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d("Bluetooth","checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
final private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastreceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        //Finding devices
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            Log.d("Bluetooth",device.getAddress()+":"+device.getName());
        }
    }
};
}
```

[image: nrf connect app]

Comment: I believe manufacturer data is something only Bluetooth Low Energy can offer but your app is searching for a Bluetooth classic device. You used Bluetooth Low Energy in your past questions about this topic. Please clarify which of the two protocols you intend to use.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan yes I found out this problem I change it to bluetoothlescanner and it works, but now I have another problem I change my nordic device from normal advertising to extended advertising how can I get the data in extended advertising?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189420/android-app-read-extended-advertising-from-nordic-nrf52840-nrf-connect-v2-0-0-pe?noredirect=1#comment129268417_73189420

Comment: I've read your question regarding extended advertisements. I do not have an answer for that. I was just commenting on this question, where you search for Bluetooth Classic devices instead of BLE devices