# Android App Read Extended Advertising Data

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-5

I'm using ESP32 for bluetooth 5 periodic extended advertising. I am trying to receive the extended advertising data on an android app. I cannot log the advertisement data on the android app code end. The data I do receive with `Log.d("MainActivity", "scanRec " + new String(scanRecord, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` is the name of the advertisment which is configured in advertisement fields, but no sight of the advertisement data.

Here is a similar issue from a year ago [Android app read extended advertising from Nordic nrf52840 nrf connect v2.0.0 periodic_adv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189420/android-app-read-extended-advertising-from-nordic-nrf52840-nrf-connect-v2-0-0-pe?noredirect=1#comment129268417_73189420)

I am testing on a bluetooth 5 android device. Does android not support logging extended advertising data? Is there an app I can use to verify extended advertisement data being received?

````
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();

                Log.d("MainActivity", "result.device " + device.getAddress());

                byte[] scanRecord = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "scanRec " + new String(scanRecord, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                Log.d("len", "len " + result.getScanRecord().getBytes().length);
        

        }```

I am trying to log extended advertisement data. When I use scanRecord.getBytes(), I only get the advertisement name. I expect to see the extended advertisement data.
````

Comment: @JayLin1119 Did you get this to work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189420/android-app-read-extended-advertising-from-nordic-nrf52840-nrf-connect-v2-0-0-pe?noredirect=1#comment129268417_73189420